# squid Which url in my file is matching

Tags: squid

i'm trying to open a web, but my squid is blocking that url, in squid.conf, i have this

```
acl neverallow url_regex -i "/usr/local/squid/etc/blacklist/neverallow"
http_access deny neverallow
```

if i comment the `http_access` line, i'm able to open the url, so, i open the file looking for the domain name, or something that looks like the url i'm trying to open, but, couldn't find nothing with my own eyes, so, i'm not an expert in linux, and i don't know how to google this, my question is, is there a way that i can manually( a command, program, etc.) test the url i'm trying to open with the ones saved in the file and know which one is the match??

I'm using Debian 6

Comment: well regex can be tricky !! it would be helpful if you had included "neverallow" files' content and the website you were trying to visit via proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the DEBUG_OPTIONS ?

```
debug_options ALL,1 33,2 28,9
```

And then take a look to cache.log

Don't forget comment the above line after debugging....

Answer (score 1):

Try this script. It should be used in this manner:

```
$ cat your_url_regex_list_file | ./script.pl url_to_be_tested
```

so that,

```
$ cat blacklist.txt | ./script.pl playboy.com
```

will show the line number of the lines matching the string provided within the file.

Regards.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $url = $ARGV[0];
chomp($url);
my $tst = 0;
my $lnb = 1;

print "Searching: [$url]...\n";
while (<STDIN>)
{
    my $item = $_;
    chomp($item);
    $lnb++;

    if ($url =~ /$item/)
    {
            print "! $lnb [$url] in |$item| \n";
            $tst++;
    }
}

if ($tst == 0) { print "no one found\n"; }
```

Comment: Your script is awesome, thanks, but one more thing, what about if i try with something like this `(http://|www\.)in\.com`, i get en error like this `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `http://'`

Comment: It also doesn't work with url like this: `http://translate.google.com.cu/?sl=es&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&eotf=1&text=seguridad+inform%C3%A1tica&file=#submit`